# Static analysis for js syntax

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, ecmascript-5

In project I work on we are in process of migrating our JS modules to TypeScript. We have to support IE11 so a lot of modern JS syntax is not allowed in our JS modules. At the moment we have a lot of modules which are still in JS(not migrated yet) and some of them migrated and all new ones written in TS. TS modules are compiled to JS, and then in build process we combine the result of compilation which is targeted to ES5 with modules which were written in JS. It happens from time to time that someone by mistake use some ES6 syntax when fixing something in module which is not yet migrated and the error is caught during runtime when code is executed on IE11. I wonder if there is any tool which provides analysis if code is correct ES5 syntax, best if it can be configurable with some features because we use some polyfills.

Comment: If you're migrating to TypeScript but not using a transpiler, how does that work at all?

Comment: @Pointy Truth is I was wondering the same thing

Comment: You can't use typescript without a transpiler

Comment: @Pointy modules written in JS are using syntax which is correct for IE 11, TypeScript modules are compiled with target es5, one TS file -> one JS file then we have some our own architecture which gathers all modules and create a bundle

Comment: @ManosKounelakis ok, maybe I was not clear in description. We use compiler for TypeScript, we not using anything for JS

Comment: It sounds like you are *keeping* some JS files (not converting them to TS), and *those JS files* need to be checked. If correct then please rephrase the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are seeking a tool for checking the use of ES6 syntax.

But I think the more efficient way is to use ES6 syntax in development side and transpile it into ES5 in production side (or browsers you target).

Please check:

- [How to Convert ES6 into ES5 using Babel](https://medium.com/@SunnyB/how-to-convert-es6-into-es5-using-babel-1b533d31a169)
- [last 2 versions](https://jamie.build/last-2-versions)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has an option called `--target ES5`. The javascript code that the typescript compiler outputs is in Javascript ES5.
By default it is ES3.